# Physical file access in AWS S3

Tags: c#, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to move some local application into the Amazon cloud which internally works on the `FileInfo` to process some files.

I know about the bucket concept as well as the file adaption using `S3FileInfo` which is pointing to the stored files within the buckets.

But since the application is using `FileInfo` I was wondering if there is any chance I can somehow create a `FileInfo` instance pointing to a file within buckets?

Answer (score 2):

[FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class cannot be used to work with S3 objects directly. A couple of things you can do:

1. Map the S3 folder to a drive on the machine

You can use a tool like [TntDrive](http://tntdrive.com/). Then you can access files you'd normally do, something like:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"Z:\Path\myfile.doc");
```

2. You can create an abstraction layer while accessing files. I recently worked on something like that in a project. What I did was access the objects through a common interface. You can have a look at the code snippet below.

This way file system dependency is encapsulated inside TextFilePersistanceProvider class only and the remaining application can work with any source.

```
public interface IGamePersistanceProvider
{
    void Save(Game game);
}

public class TextFilePersistanceProvider : IGamePersistanceProvider
{
    private IConfigurationProvider _configurationProvider;
    public TextFilePersistanceProvider(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    {
        _configurationProvider = configurationProvider;
    }

    public void Save(Game game)
    {
        if (game == null) { throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected parameter"); }

        var filePath = _configurationProvider.GetValue<string>("LatestGamePath");

        var gameAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(game, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, gameAsJson);
    }
}

public class S3PersistanceProvider : IGamePersistanceProvider
{
    private IConfigurationProvider _configurationProvider;
    public S3PersistanceProvider(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
    {
        _configurationProvider = configurationProvider;
    }

    public void Save(Game game)
    {
        if (game == null) { throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected parameter"); }

        var gameAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(game, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        });

        string accessKey = _configurationProvider.GetValue<dynamic>("S3Credentials").AccessKey.ToString();
        string secretKey = _configurationProvider.GetValue<dynamic>("S3Credentials").SecretKey.ToString();
        string bucketName = _configurationProvider.GetValue<dynamic>("S3Credentials").BucketName.ToString();
        string key = game.Name;

        using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey), RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
        {
            var transferUtil = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
            var memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(gameAsJson));
            transferUtil.Upload(memStream, bucketName, key);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the approaches. For solution it would require to modify the application which I was trying to avoid. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @derape: No problem, the question doesn't mention avoiding code change so I added the 2nd method as well. The first one would work without code modification but would require a tool installation. Anyway just my 2 cents as they say :-)

Comment: Can TNT drive be used within AWS? Or is it just a desktop client application? Maybe I did not put the question correctly, but I do not want to run the application from a windows client talking to the cloud, but put the application itself in the cloud using its files system

Comment: Hmm, maybe wwe are not on teh same page. What do you mean by putting in the cloud? If it's a C# application it would require to be deployed on a Windows machine (unless you're using Mono) and be it local or on AWS you still need to access S3 from a Windows environment. Anyway, sorry I can't be of any more help.